# SELECT inside an UPDATE query

Tags: java, sql

I'm trying to select a inner table while running an update, but I keep receiving an syntax error can anyone see what I'm doing wrong Thanks.

```
Syntax error: Encountered "SELECT" at line 1, column 94.

String sql =  "UPDATE MEMBER SET FIRSTNAME=?, LASTNAME=?, STREETADDRESS=?, CITY=?, STATE=?, ZIP=?, PHONE=?, SELECT MEMBERSHIPID WHERE MEMNAME=? WHERE MEMBERID=?";
                                PreparedStatement stmt = db.getPreparedStatement(sql);
                                stmt.setString(1, fName);
                                stmt.setString(2, lName);
                                stmt.setString(3, streetA);
                                stmt.setString(4, city);
                                stmt.setString(5, state);
                                stmt.setString(6, zc);
                                stmt.setString(7, phon);
                                stmt.setString(8, memSelection); 
                                stmt.setInt(9, Integer.parseInt(memberID));
```

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that `SELECT`?

Comment: I'm trying to select a `MEMBERID` that matches `MEMNAME` which is selected via a combobox and update with the rest of the query @Nick

Comment: Does that come from the same table?

Comment: No `MEMEBRSHIPID` and `MEMNAME` is is a different table named `MEMBERSHIP`

Comment: And is that `MEMBERSHIPID` the one you want to update?

Comment: Yes while matching the id to `MEMNAME`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write your `SELECT` as an assignment from a subquery (enclosed in parentheses), and also specify the table you are selecting the value from:

```
UPDATE MEMBER 
SET FIRSTNAME=?, 
    LASTNAME=?, 
    STREETADDRESS=?, 
    CITY=?, 
    STATE=?, 
    ZIP=?,
    PHONE=?,
    MEMBERSHIPID = (SELECT MEMBERSHIPID 
                    FROM MEMBERSHIP 
                    WHERE MEMNAME=?)
WHERE MEMBERID=?
```

Comment: This gives me another exception `Encountered "WHERE" at line 1, column 136.`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, just noticed and fixed it. I'm still not sure about the subquery... if you could add table structures to your question it would make it easier to get it correct.

Comment: @Hightower98 ok - based on the diagrams I think I have it right now.

Comment: For some reason that's not working either...I get another exception saying `Encountered "MEMBERSHIPID" at line 9, column 5.` and I double checked the answer and compared it and it's all the same

Comment: @Hightower98 sorry again - missed the comma at the end of `PHONE=?`

Comment: Ahhh that was it...it works now! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Hightower98 no worries - apologies for the missteps along the way but I'm glad we got there in the end. I've evened up your votes...